# jsonschema validating two different json responses

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I have two different JSON responses, each with different field names, however both validate successfully with the defined schema using jsonschema library.

Here is the defined schema

```
query_schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties" : {
        "pltfrm_nm": {"type" : "string"},
        "srvr_nm": {"type": "string"},
        "db_nm": {"type": "string"},
        "tbl_nm": {"type": "string"},
        "ip_addr_id": {"type": "string"},
        "usr_id": {"type": "string"},
        "sql_txt": {"type": "string"},
        "timestmp": {"type": "string"},
    },
}
```

and here is two different responses:

```
input = {'pltfrm_nm': 'p1', 'srvr_nm': 'server', 'db_nm': 'some db', 'tbl_nm': 'some table',
         'ip_addr_id': '999.999.9999', 'usr_id': 'my id', 'sql_txt': "sql text here", 'timestmp': 'aaaa)'}
validate(instance=input, schema=query_schema)

input = {'why': 'p1', 'does': 'server', 'this': 'some db', 'still': 'some table',
         'validate': '999.999.9999', 'i': 'my id', 'do': "sql text here", 'not': 'aaaa',
         'understand': 'hello'}
validate(instance=input, schema=query_schema)
```

in the second input I named all the fields different and added a new field `understand` as well. Neither of these throw a ValidationError. Here is the library: https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/. Why does the second one not throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#properties) states:

> By default, providing additional properties is valid:
>
> The additionalProperties keyword is used to control the handling of
>   extra stuff, that is, properties whose names are not listed in the
>   properties keyword. By default any additional properties are allowed.
>
> The additionalProperties keyword may be either a boolean or an object.
>   If additionalProperties is a boolean and set to false, no additional
>   properties will be allowed.
>
> Reusing the example above, but this time setting additionalProperties
>   to false.

So try to add that to your `query_schema`:

```
query_schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties" : {
        "pltfrm_nm": {"type" : "string"},
        "srvr_nm": {"type": "string"},
        "db_nm": {"type": "string"},
        "tbl_nm": {"type": "string"},
        "ip_addr_id": {"type": "string"},
        "usr_id": {"type": "string"},
        "sql_txt": {"type": "string"},
        "timestmp": {"type": "string"},
    },
  "additionalProperties": False
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON Schema is constraint based rather than permission based.
An empty JSON Schema `{}` means anything is valid.

Let's take a look at what constraint the keyword `properties` adds...

> Validation succeeds if, for each name that appears in both the
> instance and as a name within this keyword's value, the child
> instance for that name successfully validates against the
> corresponding schema.
>
> Omitting this keyword has the same behavior as an empty object.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.4

This means, the schema of the value of a key in the `properties` object, is applicable to the corrosponding value in the JSON instance.

Taking your example:

```
...    
    "properties" : {
            "pltfrm_nm": {"type" : "string"}
    }
...
```

`pltfrm_nm` must be a string.

That's the only constraint the above snippit is implying.

Are you expecting keys not listed in `proprties` to cause a validation error?
If so, you need to specify that fact.

To specify no additional properties beyond those defined in `properties`, you need to use `additionalProperties`

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.6

I'd recomend you take a look through our learning resource at http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/ and http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/ for an introduction to JSON Schema.